# Calling an object declared like a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

In the following code, I am trying to call a method which is declared like an object. How would I go about calling the function?

```
var draw = function() {
    anotherFunction();
}

draw();
```

I get an error "TypeError: Property 'draw' of object [object Window] is not a function "

Thanks.

Comment: Where is var draw defined? Inside another function?

Comment: The above code works fine, can you post your full code, so we can see where it is being called?

Comment: It looks to me like this code should work.

Comment: If your `var` statement is in global scope, that will work just fine. Based on your error message, `draw` is not visible in the scope where you call it.

Comment: You shouldn't have an issue with what your code. You more than likely have another issue around the draw function that is the real error and making draw not defined (such as missing matching () or {}).

Comment: Other than a missing semicolon (which wouldn't cause a problem unless the code you've given is all on one line), there is nothing wrong with the posted code.

Comment: What's interesting is the `Property 'draw' of object [object Window]` part; what would cause this to occur? You're calling an `init()`, are you waiting until the DOM is loaded/ready? Are you defining your `var foo = function(){...};` *after* you call `init()`? Javascript does not hoist variable functions to the top of the scope, so you could be referencing a function that does not get defined until after you're calling it. But. The `Window` and `Property` part makes me wonder. Can you `console.log(this, draw);` *right above* where you're getting the error? I'm suspicious about that.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Interesting, I think you are on to something. I'll test it out tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Javascript scoping lesson; when you do:

```
 function someFunction() {
      var foo = 'bar';
 }
 someFunction();
 // foo doesn't exist
```

that `foo` variable only lives as long as it takes to execute someFunction; after that it's gone.

You can solve this problem by setting foo on the "global object", ie. "window":

```
 function someFunction() {
      window.foo = 'bar';
 }
 someFunction();
 // foo does exist!
```

however, unless you have a very small site, that will get messy very fast (programming languages have scopes for a reason: putting everything in the global space is very hard to work with).

Therefore, what you really need to do is look more carefully at what's creating foo (well, in your case `draw`) and  what's using foo (`draw`), and see if you can't get the two closer together, or have the function that creates `draw` return it, or something like that.